# Adapting program from single to multicore

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I am considering a programming project. Will run under Ubuntu or other Linux OS on a small board. Quad core x86 - N-Series Pentium. The software generates 8 fast signals; square wave pulse trains for stepper motor motion control of 4 axes. Step signals being 50-100 KHz maximum, but usually slower. Want to avoid jitter in these stepping signals (call it good fidelity), so that around 1-2us for each thread loop cycle would be a nice target. The program does other kinds of tasks, like read/write hard drive, Ethernet, continues update on the graphics display, keyboard. The existing Single core programs just can not process motion signals with this kind of timing and require external hardware/techniques to achieve this.

I have been reading other posts here, like on a thread running selected core, continuously. The exact meaning in these posts is "lose", not sure really what is meant. Continuous might mean testing every minute or ?????

So, I might be wordy, but it will clear I hope. The considered program has all the threads, routines, memory, shared memory all included. I am not considering that this program launches another program or service. Other threads are written in this program and launched when the program starts up. I will call this signal generating thread the **FAST THREAD**.

The **FAST THREAD** is to be launched to an otherwise "free" core. It needs to be the only thread that runs on the core. Hopefully, the OS thread scheduler component on that core can be "turned off", so that it does not even interrupt on that core to decide what thread runs next. In looking at the processor manual, Each core has a counter timer chip. Is it possible then that I can use it to provide a continuous train of interrupts then into my "locked in" **FAST THREAD** for timing purposes? This is the range of about 1-2 us. If not, then just reading one channel on that CTC to provide software sync. This fast thread will, therefore, see (experience) no delays from the interrupts issued in the other cores and associated multicore fabric. This **FAST THREAD**, when running, will continue to run until the program closes. This could be hours.

Input data to drive this **FAST THREAD** will be common shared memory defined in the program. There are also hardware signals for motion limits (From GPIOs or SDI port). If any go TRUE, that forces a programmed halt all motion. It does not need a 1~2us response. It could go to a slower Motion loop.

Ah, the output:

Some motion data is written back to the shared memory (assigned for this purpose). Like current location, and current loop number,

Some signals need to be output (the 8 outputs). There are numerous free GPIOs. Not sure of the path taken to get the signaled GPIO pin to change the output. The system call to Linux initiates the pin change event. There is also an SDI port available, running up to the 25Mhz clock. It seems these ports (GPIO, UART, USB, SDI) exist in the fabric that is not on any specific core. I am not sure of the latency from the issuance of these signals in the program until the associated external pin actually presents that signal. In the fast thread, even 10us would be OK, if it was always the same latency! I know that will not be so, there will jitter. I need to think on this spec.

There will possibly be a second dedicated core (similar to above) for slower motion planning. That leaves two cores for everything thing else. Since then everything else items (sata, video screen, keyboard ...) are already able to work in a single core, then the remaining two cores should be great.

At close of program, the **FAST THREAD** returns the CTC and any other device on its core back to "as it was", re-enables the OS components in this core to their more normal operation. End of thread.

**Concluding:** I have described the overall program, so as for you to understand what I want to do with this **FAST THREAD** running, how responsive it needs to be, and that it needs to be undisturbed!! This processor runs in the 1.5 ~ 2.0 GHz range. It certainly can do the repeated calculations in the required time frame.

**DESIRED:** I do not know the system calls that would allow me to use a selected x86 core in this way. Any pointers would be helpful. Any manual or document that described these calls/procedures.

Can this use of a core also be done in windows 7,10)?

Thanks for reading and any pointers you have.

Stan

Comment: Look into [cgroups](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html) and/or [cpuset](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html).

Comment: On windows you can use `SetProcessAffinityMask` / `SetThreadAffinityMask`, on non-windows systems this functionality may vary or be unavailable so you'll need to look at particular os documentation.

Comment: How do you plan to get the signals out to the steppers?  A parallel port?  In my experience, generating the stepper signals is more appropriately left to external hardware.  It is a good FPGA application.  Trivial on an FPGA platform, difficult to impossible on a PC platform.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the responses. Shawn, I have looked into these now. Takes some time, as you can understand. Gives me some thought. VTT, I have used the Affinity masks. That WILL limit the choice of cores that thread process can run, It does not stop other thread / process from also running in those/that core.

Comment: Hello the Posting. Both writing and reading comments gives pause to think. I was worried about the task scheduler component that I assume is running in each core, only worried about the one in the core I want to use for the FAST THREAD. After looking into the cgrouips & cpuset, I rea into priorities. So, of course I need to set affinity to the chosen core, But also then set priority to the highest level (windows to 31 or Linux to 99). I am not sure if that is enough to keep other threads from running there? System threads? If there is a sys scheduling code int he core? Jump relative to next->

Comment: If there is system scheduling code that runs in this core, what is the interrupt or execution rate of that scheduler? Quantum? What got me thinking was when I considered how my FAST THREAD would handle the calculations / algorithm during each 1~2us (I could slow a bit 2-3us, 1~2 is just a target) and that this core is running 1.5Ghz or better. Then how long would the scheduler run for during each execution. Less than 1us? It would be nice just to eliminate the scheduler thread from running, but if its execution is short enough, it may be OK. Thoughts. I have yet to find much on this operation.